# Why my website screenshot results become Chinese?

Tags: node.js, capture

I made an API to get a screenshot of a website using Nodejs. I use the NPM capture-website library and in the options I use launchOptions '--no-sandbox' and '--disable-setuid-sandbox'. but every time I want to take a website from Google it always changes to Chinese. What configuration should I do?

this is my options:

```
const options = {
 width: 1366,
 height: 768,
 type: 'jpeg',
 fullPage: false,
 delay: 5,
 overwrite: true,
 launchOptions: {
  args: [
   '--no-sandbox',
   '--disable-setuid-sandbox'
  ]
 }
};
```

This is an example:
[image]